# Get access to current_user in Doorkeeper overriden layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, authorization, doorkeeper

Since Doorkeeper is an isolated Engine we have no access to whatever you did in `ApplicationController`. But what if you need a current_user? What could be a workaround here?

The first idea is to monkey-patch `ActionController::Base`. Any better thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

My doorkeeper implementation was inside of the base app so this wont help if you are using a separate engine but will if you use the same rails app so I will share here:

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  private

  def current_user
    if doorkeeper_token
      return current_resource_owner
    end
    # fallback to auth with warden if no doorkeeper token
    warden.authenticate(:scope => :user) 
  end

  # Needed for doorkeeper find the user that owns the access token
  def current_resource_owner
    User.find(doorkeeper_token.resource_owner_id) if doorkeeper_token
  end    

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless there are no answers, may be my own dirty monkey patch will be useful to someone.

in initializers/action_controller_patch.rb:

```
module ActionController
  Base.class_eval do

    def current_user
      @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
    end
    helper_method :current_user

  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find it on this page.

https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper/wiki/Using-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-flow

I am using credential auth pattern, so in my case this works.

```
Doorkeeper.configure do
  resource_owner_from_credentials do |routes|
    request.params[:user] = {:email => request.params[:username], :password => request.params[:password]}
    request.env["devise.allow_params_authentication"] = true
    request.env["warden"].authenticate!(:scope => :user)
  end
end
```